# Win32 - determine if path has jumbo icon available

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I have some code to get jumbo icons from a file:

```
// Get the image list index of the icon
SHFILEINFO sfi;
if (!SHGetFileInfo(pszPath, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX)) return NULL;

// Get the jumbo image list
IImageList *piml;
if (FAILED(SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO, IID_PPV_ARGS(&piml)))) return NULL;

// Extract an icon
HICON hico;
piml->GetIcon(sfi.iIcon, ILD_SCALE|ILD_TRANSPARENT, &hico);
```

Now, the problem is, if the path doesn't have a *256x256* icon associated with it, I don't want the icon returned by the *ImageList*.  (It will helpfully take the 32x32 and put it in a 256x256 icon, which I cannot use).

So, is there a way to find out, if the icon that is (would be) associated with a path has a jumbo icon for it, or is indeed just going to be a scaled 32x32?  If not, I'll just get the regular system icon.

### NOTE:

Final solution inspired by Jonathan below:

```
HBITMAP hbitmapForFile(LPCWSTR path, int w, int h)
{
    IShellItemImageFactory *pif;    
    HBITMAP hbm;

    SIZE sz = { w, h };
    SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pif));
    pif->GetImage(sz, SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT, &hbm);
    pif->Release();
    return hbm;
}
```

I took the resulting `HBITMAP` and put it into a *STATIC* control with `SS_BITMAP`.

One important thing I learned:  You *cannot* use the `IShellItemImageFactory` from within a *HookProc*.  Known Windows limitation; I had to `PostMessage` to the window and then use it.

Comment: Doesn't `ILD_SCALE` mean it should be scaled?

Comment: You might want to try using `LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx` or `PrivateExtractIcons`.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yah, I had hoped that too, but it doesn't help. :( In fact it caused problems elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471020/drawiconex-leaving-mask-artifacts)

Comment: @MarcWan: I think I've run into that problem before... have you tried using `DrawIcon` instead of `DrawIconEx` by any chance?

Comment: @Mehrdad Haha, good thought, but that actually made it worse :( It made even my big icons look tiny. Ai.

Comment: @Jay: `PrivateExtractIcons` is an excellent idea, except I need one missing step: Given _c:\docs\user\my.doc_, how do I get _c:\pf\microsft\office\winword.exe|iconid_ where the icon lives? … Suggestions where to look?  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcWan: Ah haha interesting. If you're *really* in the mood, you can try extracting the bitmap of the icon with `GetIconInfo`, and then resizing the bitmap manually with `StretchBlt` (`HALFTONE` scaling), and then converting it back to an icon and drawing it with `DrawIcon`. =P Not sure if it's worth the effort though.

Comment: @MarcWan: Regarding your last question to Jay: `IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation` should give you the location, but using it is painful. :( Take a look at [ReactOS](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/d71/shell32__main_8cpp_ac000f11a5ff32ca2ed60da1ea4185e08.html#ac000f11a5ff32ca2ed60da1ea4185e08) maybe... the way I usually do it is something like `LPITEMIDLIST shidl = ILCreateFromPath(normalizedPath);` then `SHBindToParent(shidl, IID_IShellFolder, &parent, &shidlChild))` followed by `parent->GetUIObjectOf(*this, 1, &shidlChild, IID_IExtractIcon, NULL, &pei)`, and then I use the `IExtractIcon`. YMMV.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, there's the kicker — I know HOW to stretch, but I only want to stretch those that are NOT 256x256. How do I know? 'IImageList::GetIcon' w JUMBO returns 256x256 no matter what icon is. Need to learn how to detect which ones are small, which are not.

Comment: @MarcWan: Ah, yeah, I indeed understood the question, but I misread your last comment, when you said "it made even my big icons look tiny". So what if you do the following? *Don't* use `ILD_SCALE`, and ask it to give you the original-sized icon -- then use `GetIconInfo` to get the bitmap of the icon, and `GetObject` to get the size of the bitmap. That should tell you the size of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proper way to do this is to not use `SHGetFileInfo` but instead to use the `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage` method with the `SIIGBF_THUMBNAILONLY` flag.

Comment: YES. This pretty much invalidates everything else I have asked in the last two days.  WOO.